# Just installed Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS on my GPU server, why is my machine going to sleep / standby?

Tags: server, 20.04, suspend

I just installed the server version of Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, and it appears that my machine is going to sleep... ?

How do I disable sleep mode?

I triple-checked, and it is indeed the server version that was installed. It's seems odd that a server OS would even have a sleep mode?

I plugged in a screen and also noticed a purple background with a menu bar at the top(?) I don't understand, shouldn't it just be a shell?

Thanks!